# SQL Select Columns.. IF NULL then Select other Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I have a view like this:

```
ID| Key | Product | Item | Block | Source | Title | Text | Type | H1 | H2 | H3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 456 | abcd    | def  |  1    |  TP    | QWERT | YUIP | tgr  | A1 | A2 | A3 |
2 | 567 | fhrh    | klo  |  1    |  GT    | TREWQ | ITGF | trp  | A1 | A2 | A3 |
3 | 891 | ufheu   | yut  |  2    |  FR    | WERTY | MNBV | uip  |NULL|NULL|NULL|
```

I want to export some of these columns into a existing, empty table.  I want to select the first six columns and then select the other columns like an hierarchy going from right to left.

If H1, H2 and H3 are NOT null, they should come in the output and Title, Text and Type should be NULL (even though they contain values).

If H1, H2 and H3 are NULL, i want thet Title, Text and Type to be in the output.

It should be something like this:

```
ID| Key | Product | Item | Block | Source | Title | Text | Type | H1 | H2 | H3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 456 | abcd    | def  |  1    |  TP    | NULL  | NULL | NULL | A1 | A2 | A3 |
2 | 567 | fhrh    | klo  |  1    |  GT    | NULL  | NULL | NULL | A1 | A2 | A3 |
3 | 891 | ufheu   | yut  |  2    |  FR    | WERTY | MNBV | uip  |NULL|NULL|NULL|
```

Can anybody help me with this? Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What if H1 is not null but H2 and H3 are?

Comment: Your logic is hard to follow.   For instance, do you want six additional columns or just three?  What do you want to do when some of the columns are NULL but not all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've wrapped all column names in [square brackets] because you're using reserved names (Key, Text, Type) and I like consistency, it's worth breaking this habit as soon as possible.

If your criteria is that all three columns (H1, H2, H3) need to be NULL then you'll want something like this;

```
SELECT [ID]
    ,[key]
    ,[Product]
    ,[Item]
    ,[Block]
    ,[Source]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN H1 IS NULL
            AND H2 IS NULL
            AND H3 IS NULL
            THEN [Title]
        ELSE NULL
        END AS [Title]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN H1 IS NULL
            AND H2 IS NULL
            AND H3 IS NULL
            THEN [Text]
        ELSE NULL
        END AS [Text]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN H1 IS NULL
            AND H2 IS NULL
            AND H3 IS NULL
            THEN [Type]
        ELSE NULL
        END AS [Type]
    ,H1
    ,H2
    ,H3
FROM DataTable
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want the comparison column by column, then use `coalesce()`:

```
select ID, Key, Product, Item, Block, Source,
       (case when h1 is not null then null else title end) as title,
       (case when h2 is not null then null else text end) as text,
       (case when h3 is not null then null else type end) as type,
       coalesce(h1, title) as h1,
       coalesce(h2, text) as h2,
       coalesce(h3, type) as h3
from t;
```

However, I'm not sure if you mean all three columns at the same time:

```
select ID, Key, Product, Item, Block, Source,
       (case when h1 is null and h2 is null and h3 is null then title end) as title,
       (case when h1 is null and h2 is null and h3 is null then text end) as text,
       (case when h1 is null and h2 is null and h3 is null then type end) as type,
       (case when h1 is null and h2 is null and h3 is null then NULL else h1 end) as h1,
       (case when h1 is null and h2 is null and h3 is null then NULL else h2 end) as h2,
       (case when h1 is null and h2 is null and h3 is null then NULL else h3 end) as h3
from t;
```

Comment: Yes i needed all the columns at the same time, works great except for the column aliases (title, text, type), but that's nothing..

Thank you very for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this  (Concatenation will return null if any value is null)

```
--When H1,H2 and H3 Null
Declare  @H1 AS Varchar(50)=NULL
        ,@H2 AS Varchar(50)=NULL
        ,@H3 AS Varchar(50)=NULL
        ,@Title AS Varchar(50)='Title'
        ,@Text  AS Varchar(50)='Text'
        ,@Type  AS Varchar(50)='Type'

SELECT ISNULL(@H1+@H2+@H3,@Title) Title
       ,ISNULL(@H1+@H2+@H3,@Text) [Text]
       ,ISNULL(@H1+@H2+@H3,@Type) [Type]
       ,@H1 H1
       ,@H2 H2
       ,@H3 H3
```

When H1,H2 OR H3 has  value

```
Declare  @H1 AS Varchar(50)='H1'
        ,@H2 AS Varchar(50)='H2'
        ,@H3 AS Varchar(50)='H3'
        ,@Title AS Varchar(50)='Title'
        ,@Text  AS Varchar(50)='Text'
        ,@Type  AS Varchar(50)='Type'

SELECT  CASE ISNULL(@H1+@H2+@H3,'') WHEN '' THEN @Title ELSE Null END Title
       ,CASE ISNULL(@H1+@H2+@H3,'') WHEN '' THEN @Text ELSE Null END [Text] 
       ,CASE ISNULL(@H1+@H2+@H3,'') WHEN '' THEN @Type ELSE Null END [Type]
       ,@H1 H1
       ,@H2 H2
       ,@H3 H3
```